# if($_GET['info'] ==...) not checking

Tags: php, if-statement, get

I wrote a little check to display succes messages whenever a form is validated succesfully. However the check I use doesn't work. it doesn't matter what $_GET['info'] is, it just shows all messages unless $_GET['info] is empty. so even when info = loggin it shows all three messages. any help?

```
                if(!empty($_GET['info'])){
                    if($_GET['info'] == "succes-paid"){
                        echo "<p class='succes'>De bestelling/inschrijving is succesvol verlopen.</p>";
                    }
                    if($_GET['info'] == "succes-register"){
                        echo "<p class='succes'>U werd succesvol geregistreerd.</p>";
                    }
                    if($_GET['info'] == "login"){
                        echo "<p class='succes'>U werd succesvol ingelogd.</p>";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: See the semicolon after the if statements: `;` <- remove them!

Answer (score 2):

You have a semi-colon after each of your if statements. The semi-colon means "finish the statement". Therefore your program thinks that you are done with the if and everything in your braces is treated as a block separate from your if statement. That is why those blocks are always executing.

Comment: oowh damn, thanks. This is awkward :(

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the semicolon right after the condition of the `if`.

That line is actually two statements. The first is the `if` with condition, followed by an 'empty' statement, ended by a semi-colon. The second is a compound statement (a block of statements within a set of `{ .. }`. The compound statement doesn't have a condition at all, so it is always executed.

```
 if($_GET['info'] == "succes-paid")  ; {echo 'x'}
 condition with no statement  -----^ ^ ^--------^-- compound statement without condition 
                                     \_The semi-colon that separates them.
```

And you have this situation three times, hence three lines of output.